# Css transition not working on scrollable div in body overflow:hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, overflow, transition

I want to use [this header effect](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/16/on-scroll-header-effects/) on the website I am working on but with some modifications. I need to implement this on div instead of header. The problem is that this js/css effect is not working with my css which is:

`body{
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}`

Since I need this to be on some div that is scrollable I think it is not a big problem to make that possible. I just don't understand javascript so much and that is why I need your help. Here i made [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qfw1vspd/) with working animation where you can see all external js/css.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you set overflow to hidden on the body it will cut the text to the body size, so you will be unable to scroll. You can use `overflow: scroll` or `auto` (that will set it to `scroll` because the text is bigger than the body). In that way all your content will be rendered.

Comment: Thanks @ran3000 but I need my body to be overflow:hidden and to place this effect in a scrollable div.

Comment: I don't think that it's possible from your css; you have to edit the external css that you have downloaded for the effect.